# As correctly to remove class in с++

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

Sometimes it is necessary to restart a class again, but deleting it does not guarantee that its static variables will be reset. That need to do to class has left certainly?

```
auto my = new MyClass;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    delete my;
    my = new MyClass;
    my->runIs();
}
```

...

```
void MyClass::runIs()
{
    static int x = 0;
    qDebug() << ++x;
}
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

[Src in github.com](https://github.com/ggshaman888/my_example/tree/master/qt_new_delete)

Comment: `static` has many different uses and you seem to confuse them. `x` is not a static member of the class. Hence it is not "reset" when you delete the instance (though it also wouldnt be reset if it was a static member). To give a proper answer you have to explain what is the purpose of `x` and why is it `static` ?

Comment: Programming mutable static objects is a something to avoid.

Comment: You don't need `new` or `delete` here `MyClass my; my.runIs();`

Comment: The task is to fix the memory leak. Is it not possible to delete the object completely? This is a minimal example. Working code runs into this problem. A static variable is needed to limit the number of cycles, but the class sometimes needs to be restarted.

Comment: @shaman888 "_Is it not possible to delete the object completely?_" Yes, it is possible. `delete` does just that. It's just that `static` variables are not bound to the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `x` is a static variable and is not a member of the class. So it will never be reset.

What you want in this case is not a static variable but a simple member of the class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int x = 0;

    void runIs();
}

void MyClass::runIs()
{
    qDebug() << ++this->x;
}
```

Comment: `++x`. `this->` is noise. While it's occasionally needed, don't get in the habit of always writing it.

Comment: I had a lot of discussions about that, `this` may be noisy but is a lot more understandable than nothing. It's by preferences tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass* my;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    my = new MyClass;
    my->runIs();
    delete my;
}
```

...

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    close_class = false;
}

void MyClass::runIs()
{
    static int x = 0;
    if (close_class) {
        x = 0;
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << ++x;
    }
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    closeClass();
}

void MyClass::closeClass()
{
    close_class = true;
    runIs();
}
```

Comment: `x` is not a static member of the class